# Typescript: Import default from CommonJS module, export additional type from typing file

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Legacy lib.js:

```
function Foo () {...}
Foo.a = function() {...}
module.exports = Foo
```

Typing lib.d.ts:

```
declare module "foo" {
  type Type = "a"|"b"|"c"
  interface Foo {
    (a: Type): string
    ...
  }
  export = Foo
  // how do i export Type??
}
```

Consumer app.ts:

```
import Foo = require('foo')
// how do i get Type from lib.d.ts??
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old question, but I needed to answer it myself. If in this case "Foo" is the default `modules.exports`, then you can use `export default` on `Foo` in the module declaration:

```
declare module "foo" {
  export type Type = "a"|"b"|"c" // export any custom types you like

  export default interface Foo { // default works
    (a: Type): string
    ...
  }
}
```

Then elsewhere you can do:

```
import Foo, { Type } from 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do i get Type from lib.d.ts?

If is not exported you cannot get it.

Comment: See the code sample. `export = ...` only allows a single export - how do I export 1 function and 1 type using that syntax?

Comment: @bcherny you have `export =` on an *interface*. That is invalid anyways